# How convert Data class to JsonElement in kotlinx

Tags: kotlin, data-class, kotlinx, jsonelement

I'm trying to convert a kotlin dataclass to a JsonElement, is there a way to do it using kotlin?

```
@Serializable
data class SubjectContext(
    val name: String,
    var programContext: Properties? = null
)

@Serializable
data class Properties(
    val color: String,
    var large: Int
)
```

Comment: Why don't use `Gson`?

Comment: Take a look at the `kotlinx.serialization` docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization
`Json.encodeToString(Properties("red", 2))` should do the trick